# Is it Possible to Define Two Name Servers and a HTTP Host in a Unix-Based Server With Only One Static IP Address

Tags: networking, webserver, bind

Is it possible to define two globally name servers (`ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`) on the same server, with an static IP (e.g., `99.99.99.99`), that hosts the HTTP through port 80.

**Why Am I Not Avoiding the Single Point Of Failure**: I will be using a Unix-based server for development/testing my applications, even though it will create a single point of failure, it is a great and cost effective setup for me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it is also very bad practice. You would be running only a single name server instance (e.g. BIND server); you would simply define the glue records for both nameservers to resolve to the same IP.